# Android Studio: find in project explorer shortcut

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclips I have a nice button, in top left corner of project explorer, that will find the currently open file in project explorer.

Where do I find this button in Android Studio? I am reading file and I want a quick way to find it in project explorer.

My current unsatisfying solution is reading the package name and searching it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the "Project" tab label on the left and there you can at least enable the "Autoscroll from Source" setting.

I am not aware of a shortcut that does that on request and not permanently.

Update: I just tried to make a shortcut by enabling/disabling the setting but the macro recorder does not record enabling/disabling the setting, so without a macro I couldn't create a shortcut for that. So that is no alternative :/

Answer (score 6):

In project explorer window there is settings icon on the top right corner.Click it .You will see number of options , just select "Autoscroll from Source".You are done.

Comment: Works for me!  Thanks. But a keyboard shortcut is desperately needed.